# 2 Ajax calls output into separate Jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

i have asked about a similar query, but feel I should start a new question as this isn't entirely related.
I am trying to output Json from two separate files (spanish.php & italian.php).
I have got the code to work fine when i only populate one tab, but it doesn't seem to work when I try to populate both tabs.
Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

```
// TABS FUNCTIONS

         $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
         });

    // SPANISH MENU

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/spanish.php", 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            success: function (data) {
                drawTable(data);
            }               
        });
    });

    function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(data[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        var row = $("<tr />")
        $("#table2").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.course + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.price + "</td>"));
    }


    // ITALIAN MENU

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/italian.php", 
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
            success: function (dataI) {
                drawTable(dataI);
            }               
        });
    });

    function drawTable(dataI) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataI.length; i++) {
            drawRow(dataI[i]);
        }
    }

    function drawRow(rowData) {
        var row = $("<tr />")
        $("#table1").append(row);
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.course + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + rowData.price + "</td>"));
    }
```

And the tabs/html:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tab-1">Italian</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tab-2">Spanish</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="tab-1">
            <p>Italian</p>
            <table id='table1'>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>    
            </div>

            <div id="tab-2">
                <table id='table2' border="1">
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work".  What *does* it do?  What are you expecting it to do?  Are there any errors?  When you debug, where/how specifically does it fail?  What are the relevant runtime values when that happens?

Comment: Have you tried doing a console.log on the values you are getting back from the server?

Comment: Where is `jsonpCallback` function defined? See [`jQuery.ajax( [settings ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) at `jsonpCallback` _"Specify the callback function name for a JSONP request."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `$ (function () {`

Is equal to this: `$ (document) .ready (function () {`

So you do not have to put both, or put more than once. Use only once and then place your code inside.

So I tried to use your code, I just removed the `jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',` and then it worked fine, becase you don't have a [callback function](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/). In the end will be like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // SPANISH MENU
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/spanish.php", 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            drawTable(data, 1);
        }               
    });


    // ITALIAN MENU
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "http://learn.cf.ac.uk/webstudent/sem5tl/javascript/assignments/italian.php", 
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            drawTable(data, 2);
        }               
    });
});

function drawTable(data, table_number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i], table_number);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData, table_number) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#table" + table_number).append(row);
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.course + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.price + "</td>"));
}
```